# 1 VM host 2 PostgreSQL Databases

Tags: postgresql

I'm very new to postsql. Here is my situation.

There is an existing postsql running on my VM on port 1234 pointing to a database name : db1. 
Now, I want to add db2, will I need re-configure another port for ? Maybe 1235 ?

Can 1 VM host 2 PostgreSQL Databases ? How would one configure something like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Each VM can host a theoretically unlimited number of databases. The practical limits are the usual suspects - memory, disk, and CPU resource availability for the connections and internal processing said database(s) require. Simply create the new database and give access to it through the normal PostgreSQL commands (`GRANT` statements).